# Match sister rows and distribute evenly to each employees worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched for an answer but couldn't find one for my use case.

I have a worksheet where rows are not assigned to a user. I then have to assign these rows to each user on the team as evenly as possible but what is making me confused is that some rows have sister records where they need to be assigned to only one user. I am not sure how to group these rows together and make sure records are evenly disbursed.

Here's what I am trying to do.

1. Compare column B and C ( ID and Sister ) where if it finds a match on the opposite column, they will be considered a pair.
2. Count the total number of rows including ones without a sister record.
3. Evenly distribute and copy the rows based on the number worksheets. Rows with pairs need to be only on one worksheet
4. Column A  will then be filled with the associated worksheet name

[image]

Anything helps!

Comment: What do you mean by "distribute and copy the rows based on the number worksheets"? Where from that "number worksheets" to be taken? Do you mean the total unique pairs A&B? Then, what should "filled with the associated worksheet name" mean? Where from that "associated worksheet name" to be taken? Should the code insert so many sheets as unique pairs exist? If so, based on what to name these sheets? Randomly? Are there (already) the employees sheets and (somehow) their name can be match with the ID (pair ID + Sister)? If so, where in those sheets this information can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code ... add a standard Module and paste this code into it ... you would run the `DistributeRows` procedure ... the `FindSister` and `GetWksNames` procedures must be included.

I have made a number of assumptions to make this work ... they are documented in the code comments so please read and check. The code comments also give an explanation of what the code is doing for your understanding and in case you need to make adjustments.

```
Option Explicit

' assumes data is in columns A to C ... adjust following if not
Private Const mlASSIGNED_TO_COL As Long = 1

' assumes data is in rows 1 down (with row 1 being the headers) ... adjust following if not
Private Const mlHEADER_ROW As Long = 1


Sub DistributeRows()
    Dim wksData As Worksheet
    ' assums the sheet with the data is active
    Set wksData = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    ' assumes the ID column has no empty rows
    lLastRow = wksData.Cells(mlHEADER_ROW, mlASSIGNED_TO_COL + 1).End(XlDirection.xlDown).Row
    
    ' get the names of the 'other' Worksheets
    Dim vasWksNames As Variant, lWksIndex As Long
    vasWksNames = GetWksNames(wksData)
    
    Dim lRow As Long, rngSister As Range, rngIds As Range
    With wksData
        ' get a Range for the IDs ... will be used to Find matches for sisters
        Set rngIds = .Range(.Cells(mlHEADER_ROW + 1, mlASSIGNED_TO_COL + 1), .Cells(lLastRow, mlASSIGNED_TO_COL + 1))
        ' cycle through each row with an ID
        For lRow = mlHEADER_ROW + 1 To lLastRow
            ' if Assigned To is not already populated (ie because it is a 'sister row') ... assumes cells in
            ' 'Assigned to' column start empty
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(lRow, mlASSIGNED_TO_COL)) Then
                .Cells(lRow, mlASSIGNED_TO_COL).Value = vasWksNames(lWksIndex)
                ' if there is a sister ID then find the matching row and, if any, add the same Worksheet name to it
                If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(lRow, mlASSIGNED_TO_COL + 2)) Then
                    ' assumes there is only ever 1 match for a 'sister'
                    Set rngSister = FindSister(rngIds, .Cells(lRow, mlASSIGNED_TO_COL + 2))
                    If Not rngSister Is Nothing Then
                        .Cells(rngSister.Row, mlASSIGNED_TO_COL).Value = vasWksNames(lWksIndex)
                    End If
                End If
                ' change the Worksheet name index to use for the next row and/or sister
                If lWksIndex = UBound(vasWksNames) Then
                    lWksIndex = LBound(vasWksNames)
                Else
                    lWksIndex = lWksIndex + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next lRow
    End With
End Sub


' if there is a sister row then return it, otherwise return Nothing
Private Function FindSister(rngToSearch As Range, vId As Variant) As Range
    With rngToSearch
        Set FindSister = .Find(vId, _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                LookIn:=XlFindLookIn.xlValues, _
                Lookat:=XlLookAt.xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=XlSearchDirection.xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)
    End With
End Function


' get an array of Strings of all Worksheet names in the Workbook other than the name of the 'data sheet'
Private Function GetWksNames(wksData As Worksheet) As Variant
    ' assumes there is at least one other Worksheet in the Workbook, no hidden Worksheets etc
    Dim wks As Worksheet, vasWksNames As Variant, lCount As Long
    For Each wks In wksData.Parent.Worksheets
        If Not wks.Name = wksData.Name Then
            If lCount = 0 Then
                ReDim vasWksNames(0 To 0)
                vasWksNames(0) = wks.Name
            Else
                ReDim Preserve vasWksNames(0 To lCount)
                vasWksNames(lCount) = wks.Name
            End If
            lCount = lCount + 1
        End If
    Next wks
    GetWksNames = vasWksNames
End Function
```

The end result, if you have 3 other Worksheets in your Workbook named 'User A', 'User B' and 'User C':

[image]

Comment: @phrozen did you have time to test the above solution?

Comment: omg i forgot to reply to you. yes it did! thanks a bunch!